# How to preserve the matrix dimension after using apply on matrix with one row

Tags: r, matrix

I  have the following matrix:

```
> m <- matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol = 3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
> dim(m)
[1] 1 3
```

Then I apply a function on to it as follows:

```
> apply(m, 2, function(x) {
+     10 * (2**x - 1)
+ })
[1] 0 0
```

As you can see the output becomes a vector, (i.e. `dim = NULL`).
How can I preserve the dimension after using `apply`?

Comment: For completeness: `'dim<-'(apply(m, 2, function(x) {10 * (2**x - 1)}), dim(m))` ( but as Ronak wrote: no need for `apply` here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[]` to preserve the dimension

```
m[] <- apply(m, 2, function(x) 10 * (2**x - 1))
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
```

---

However, R is vectorised and such mathematical operations can be done directly without need of `apply` or any loops.

```
10 * (2**m - 1)
```